# Redirection on form submit in django with javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, python-3.x

i don't understand why this redirect is happening basically in my html i have a textinput field with id of id_location a form with id of user_form and a submit button for the form with id submit_form, what i'm trying to do is register a user and capture their address and then use geocoding to get their co-ordinates on the map and set the values of two hidden input fields for the longitude and latitude of the users location with id's of id_longitude and id_latitude respectively and finally submit the form

on the back-end they're redirected back to the homepage, now here's the problem whenever i submit the form i get redirected to a url with the location i filled in the location field in the form at the end, so for example if i fill in London i get this

```
localhost:8000/signup/London
```

and the form dosen't submit at the backend (i checked the django-admin for Users and i don't see anything new)

i've tried putting alerts in strategic locations in the javascript code but the alert shows up and redirects before i can even read it, i don't really know if this has something to do with django or the javascript i wrote, but i believe it's because of the javascript but i can provide more information about my django models and views, but basically in the django i used a one-to-one field to get more information from the user and extended the UserCreationForm

```
$('#submit_form').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var getlocation = $('#id_location').val();

$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API_KEY&address='+getlocation+'&sensor=false', function(results){


if (results.status == 'OK'){
    var latitude = results.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var longitude = results.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    $('#id_latitude').val(latitude);
    $('#id_longitude').val(longitude);

    alert('say something before submission');

    $('#user_form').submit();
}
});
});
```

i've also run my javascript through a javascript lint to check for syntax errors but there's none

also is this the best way to stop a form from submitting and modify values in the form before submitting without using ajax?

**UPDATE**
after posting my answer, i corrected some of my typos but now the form dosen't even submit

Comment: you have a typo in $getJSON should be $.getJSON I'm assuming this is a result of you copying and pasting into SO

Comment: also you're calling submit() this is going to cause a page refresh.  Why do you need to do that.  the point of jquery ajax is to avoid page refreshes etc... you just call your method and do something with the response.

Comment: it turns out the typo was there but after fixing it, i'm still getting the same behaviour (i thought i had been saved once again by SO).

Comment: your behavior is because of the submit.

Comment: as i explained earlier i'm trying to stop the form from submitting get some gecodes and then set the values of hidden fields in the form and submit it when i'm done, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: by default the submit is supposed to submit the form normally, not redirecting the to a url with the location name....i'm confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i guess i finally solved it myself with another approach, i added a change event on the location field so once the user types the information and leaves the field the event is fired and the geocoding takes place and returns the latitude and longitude, i also discovered that i had some syntax errors and wasn't accessing the values correctly. but in the main time i'll still try to figure out why the first approach wasn't working

```
$('#id_location').on('change', function(e){

var getlocation = $('#id_location').val();

$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=API_KEY&address='+getlocation+'&sensor=false', function(results){

    if (results.status == 'OK'){

    var latitude = results.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    var longitude = results.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

    $('#id_latitude').val(latitude);
    $('#id_longitude').val(longitude);

    console.log(latitude);
    console.log(longitude);
    }
});
});
```